# Sample, randomly & uniformly the partitioning of $n$ objects into $K$ groups

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I wish to sample randomly and uniformly from the set of partitions of $n$ objects into $K$ groups where the number to be assigned to each group, $n_k$ ($k = 1, 2, \dots, K$) is known.

I know that the number of partitions is

$$ \frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^K n_k!} $$

so that for say $n = 9$ and $n_1 = n_2 = n_3 = 3$, there are

$$ \frac{9!}{3!3!3!} = 1680$$

such partitions. Note I don't wish to restrict myself to equal group sizes.

How can I sample a number, say $P$, of these partitions, such that the resulting sample is drawn randomly and uniformly from the set of all such partitions?

One approach that occurred to me would be to:

1. select a group from the $K$ groups, at random
2. select at random from the $n$ observations $n_1$ of them
3. select at random a group from the remaining $K-1$ groups
4. select at random from the $n - n_1$ remaining observations
5. repeat 3 and 4 until you have filled $K - 1$ groups, assign the remaining observations to the last group.

Does that seem reasonable or am I overlooking something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a second to deduce from your example that the combinatorial objects you're interested in are [ordered set partitions](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/set_partition_ordered.html), i.e., set compositions. The linked webpage is for the ordered set partition functions of the python/cython based SAGE mathematical software.

For example, in the Sage notebook (sagenb.org):
`OS = OrderedSetPartitions(9, [3,3,3])
OS.cardinality()
1680

OS.random_element()
[{1, 2, 3}, {8, 4, 6}, {9, 5, 7}]`

The sage [source code](https://sage.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/src/combinat/set_partition_ordered.py) is readily available, though you might have to hunt for your particular function.